# How do I automatically convert a class of enumerations to VARCHAr

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

This is base interface:

```java
public interface Database {
    String getCode();
}
```

```java
public enum Gender implements Database {

    MALE("0101");
    
    private final String code;
    
    Gender(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

```java
public enum State implements Database {

    CLOSE("0201");
    
    private final String code;
    
    Gender(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

What I want:

entity attributes   **Automatic conversion**   database(varchar)

MALE   **Automatic conversion**   0101

CLOSE   **Automatic conversion**   0201

I try to use `AttributeConverter`, but when I add a subclass of `Database`, I have to define another `AttributeConverter`. Is there any other better solution?

Comment: I didn' t understand why are you trying to achieve with Database interface here?

Comment: @code_mechanic Using the default two methods (EnumType.ORDINAL or EnumType.STRING), I cannot modify the order and name

Comment: I didn't ask that, I got the use case but I am not sure how interface is helping you here, can you explain that?

Comment: @code_mechanic I want to create an AttributeConverter for the Database so that I can customize the way of storing to the database, but I found that this does not work, or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: AttributeConverter works the way it should work, but in your example you have created an interface Database in then you are implementing it in each enum so that you have to implement `getCode` method which I find useless, instead why can't you create one enum and define all your codes there and write the converter for that enum?